# clang++ : Cannot allocate an object of abstract type

Tags: c++, inheritance, abstract-class, virtual-functions

I have “Cannot allocate an object of abstract type” error.

I get it when I create an object `Be` (inheriting from abstract class `Ae`) when passing it to a method taking `const Ae&`. I thought it shouldn't be a problem when passing as a reference. The error says: `error: allocating an object of abstract class type Be`.

The logic of a program goes as follows:

```
//A.hpp
struct A : public std::exception { //Exception class
    class Ae { //Error message class
        virtual const char* message() const = 0;
        inline operator const char*() const {
            return message();
        }
    };
    // fields describing where the error occurred in file input
    int a, b, c, d;
    // string reporting what happened
    const char* msg;
    A( const Ae& e, int a, int b, int c, int d ) : a(a), b(b), c(c), d(d), msg(e)
    {}
    const char* what() const throw() { /* printing some nice report */ }
    ~A() throw () {}
};

//B.hpp 
struct B : public A {
    B( const Ae& e, int a, int b, int c, int d ) : A( e,a,b,c,d )
    {}
    struct Be : public Ae { //particular error having relevant class name e.g. IncorrectInput
        const char* message() const {
            return "Some error description";
        }
    }; // more of alikes
};

//AUser.hpp
struct AUser { // some module that will be throwing A
    int a, b, c, d;
    A Exception( const Ae& e ) {
        return A( e, a, b, c, d );
    }
};

//BUser.hpp
struct BUser : public AUser {
    void fun() { // any method
        // (...) does sth
        if ( goeswrong )
            throw Exception( B::Be() );
    }
};
```

What is wrong with my code?

To clarify the goal of such structures - AUser is CsvFile, BUser is ParticularCsvFile (with methods recognizing which field contains which datatype), A is CsvFileExceotion, B is ParticularFileException, Ae is ErrorCode, Be is for example ErrorWhenReadingPricesCell

The error pops out for line containing `throw Exception( B::Be() );` claming additionally that `note: unimplemented pure virtual method 'message' in 'Be'
        public: virtual const char* message() const = 0;`

### Edit

As requested, the *exact* g++ -Wall -pedantic -Wextra goes below.
Please note that I simplified the code above and changed names:
BUser == DividendsFile, B == DividendsFileReadingException, Be == UnexpectedStockDividend, AUser == CsvFile, A == CsvFileReadingException, Be == ErrorCode

```
quotreader2.cpp:18:5: warning: unused parameter ‘argc’ [-Wunused-parameter]
Input/DividendsFile.cpp: In member function ‘int DividendsFile::getStockDividend()’:
Input/DividendsFile.cpp:28:85: error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type ‘DividendsFileReadingException::UnexpectedStockDividend’
In file included from Input/DividendsFile.cpp:3:0:
Input/Exceptions/DividendsFileReadingException.hpp:28:12: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘DividendsFileReadingException::UnexpectedStockDividend’:
In file included from Input/CsvFile.hpp:4:0,
                 from Input/DividendsFile.hpp:4,
                 from Input/DividendsFile.cpp:2:
Input/Exceptions/CsvFileReadingException.hpp:17:37: note:   virtual const char* CsvFileReadingException::ErrorCode::message() const
make: *** [bin/test.bin] Error 1
```

Comment: Which line is the error (I've read it once, couldn't spot it)

Comment: @AlecTeal I updated the question for that info. See at the bottom.

Comment: Did you forget the virtual keyword in Be?

Comment: @FabienWarniez `B::Be` doesn't derive from anything

Comment: @FabienWarniez Be::message() is without virtual keyword in my code. Why should it be?

Comment: What does GCC say? Seriously please try it. put -Wall and -Wextra and -pedantic on

Comment: BTW this is still horrible code! But I can't see why Clang is upset.

Comment: @AlecTeal I did. For both g++ and clang++. Both yield the same minimal output as posted. The one quoted is from clang++

Comment: I thought Be was subclassing Ae but I was wrong.

Comment: Copy and paste all the build output from using GCC please, it will help.

Comment: Where's your `Exception` class that you construct from `B:Be`

Comment: @AlecTeal I posted the exact g++ output. Exception is not a class. Is a method of AUser for throwing A and supply A's constructor with data it needs which are AUser's fields, so it would be riddiculus to post is explicitly each time. So only particular Ae is given, indicating what went wrong.

Comment: Here is the new generation of smart compilers : your code is really convoluted, and they try to prevent such things to be ever written.

Comment: @infoholic_anonymous: You post *Be (inheriting from abstract class Ae)*, but in the code `Be` inherit from nothing...

Comment: I just spotted that, seriously this code is horrible, see my answer there are like 4 errors at play.

Comment: @Jarod42 yeah just spotted that!

Comment: __YOU CANNOT JUST ADD `:public Ae` TO THE CODE AND NOT UPDATE THE ERRORS YOU ARE GETTING, YOU ARE JUST BEING CRUEL NOW__

Comment: @AlecTeal I know, I had it all the time in my code. I only forgot to write it here on stack overflow. And I do apologize for that.

Comment: After adding public in `class Ae`, add missing `A::` in `class AUser`, complete some methods, it compiles fine here...

Comment: Can you please update the code to be what generated the error?  It i confusing to try to keep track of old class to new class names.

Comment: To quote a witch from Blackadder, "I see three options here, kill the other person (me, please me!), kill yourself, or kill everybody"- it's so hard to read and I'm not sure if the code you've given actually has errors, how did you forget `:public Ae` seriously?

Comment: @AlecTeal Ok, I understand you anger and appreciate help. I just didn't thought naming would be that of an issue. So tell me what should I do. Replace/add the actual code with real names g++ uses?

Comment: I suspect that OP has a typo in there code which he forgets to transcript here... (but add new ones :/)

Comment: @Jarod42 very probable :/

Comment: @AlecTeal You're being over the top and rude here. Perhaps it isn't the best-written code; I'm sure you've written some you wouldn't be proud of looking back on yourself. This whole thing so far could have been boiled down to "post some code that doesn't work here verbatim, along with the output from g++ of compiling **that exact same** code". There's no need to start yelling at and berating someone. You can always just walk away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fixing several typo-type of grammar errors, such as changing from

```
class Ae
```

to

```
struct Ae
```

,

from

```
struct Be
```

to

```
struct Be : public Ae
```

,

from

```
A Exception( const Ae& e )
```

to

```
A Exception( const A::Ae& e )
```

The code compiled perfectly in clang, so I don't get your question. Did you at least try to compile your code posted in this question?

Comment: The OP lied, he did forget the public Ae..... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20962173/clang-cannot-allocate-an-object-of-abstract-type?noredirect=1#comment31489668_20962173

Comment: My program is a lot bigger. I posted here the relevant abstract. My program does not compile and I did not forger public ae in my code, why would I lie? If that compiles, it means problem lies in different piece of code and g++ lies about the source of an issue (not the first time). And I cannot post the whole code here because it is to big...

Comment: Nobody doubt your problem. You shall then try to make a minimal example that fail to compile. People can't help if your question has no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Oh it's obvious!

Exception for some reason is a function that returns an `A`

Here:

```
A Exception( const Ae& e ) {
    return A( e, a, b, c, d );
}
```

AAAAnnnnd

```
struct A : public std::exception { //Exception class
    class Ae { //Error message class
        virtual const char* message() const = 0;
```

we have a virtual method here.

then

```
            throw Exception( B::Be() );
```

means "throw an A that results form Exception's function call"

but you CANNOT throw an A! Because A is abstract

**additionally**

exception expects a Ae, but you give it a Be, and no conversion between the two.

The compiler has actually found like 4 errors here, that's why the report is so useless (I'll be posing to the GCC mailing list the question of why it is so useless)

**Be does not inherit from anything**

```
struct Be { //particular error having relevant class name e.g. IncorrectInput
    const char* message() const {
        return "Some error description";
    }
}; // more of alikes
```

See

Comment: Why is A abstract? Ae is abstract.

Comment: Be inherits from Ae so there is conversion.

Comment: There's so much wrong with this, seriously, it's hard to read and I have no idea what you're trying to do, there's some hints here but you've confused the compiler a lot too.

Comment: Oh, it does inherit, forgot to write it :/ Btw should I change the names or what?

Comment: Start again, seriously, this is HORRIBLE to read, also if you are going to use camelCase - which I like btw, use CamelCase for typenames (classes) and camelCase for methods, that is why I assumed `Exception` was a type. @infoholic_anonymous

Comment: Please refer to actual names for the classes from the bottom. If using them you get the idea what I meant to do, I'd be glad to hear suggestions for better soultions. AUser reads csv file, stores info in which line it is, which cell. Ae needs it to print a good error message. I needed Exception(), I throw a lot, it'd redundant to post each time same data.

Comment: @infoholic_anonymous you know about macros? Also do you really? Objects should be self-contained things that do a job, the exception object should contain the info on what went wrong, not be wrapped by some unnecessary function!

Comment: You need more practice, you are clearly new and it's good you are learning but seriously, start again, I can't really read your code, and I've never EVER had to use such a pattern, or needed an exception function, sometimes I use a macro to automatically insert filename and line number for me, but that's it!

Comment: @AlecTeal by creating an A object in the 'Be' constructor, he immediately creates 'Ae'. in my opinion, the rest is just the same thing...

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you didn't actually implement some abstract method declared in class A in class B. If there is an unimplemented abstract method, then the class itself (B) remains abstract. It is a compilation error to try to create a new instance of an abstract class (since the compiler would not know what to do if it got a call to that unimplemented method). Check that all abstract methods declared in A are implemented in B, and you should be fine...

To further hone in on your erro:

```
struct Be { //particular error having relevant class name e.g. IncorrectInput
        const char* message() const {
            return "Some error description";
        }
    };
```

class Ae has declared that message() is virtual... Class B is not implementing this virtual method, struct Be is. struct Be is a part of B, it's not itself extending Ae. Therefore the method is unimplemented as part of B... Not sure why this is being downvoted...

Comment: But `B::Be` denotes a complete type. It doesn't need `B` to exist, also if what you say is true we should get a __linker__ error. To undefined vtable, or a runtime crash if it couldn't devirtualise during compiling.

Comment: You didn't implement it in B, you put it inside Be

Comment: Class `Be` has NOTHING to do with `A` other than being in the namespace of it (classes are namespaces with structure).  Again, imagine you only had header files, it's the LINKERS job to link, not compiling stuff, you can use it in files that don't declare the virtuals, but the linker will whine!

Comment: So i have also made a semantic mistake here. It's class Ae, not A declaring a method virtual... How are you defining that Be is extending Ae ? That's what i'm trying to get at.. It looks like you are just declaring that B has a new inner type Be. There is nothing to me that indicates Be extends Ae and therefore implements its message function. B has two inner types, Ae and Be, unrelated in terms of inheritance.

Comment: There's so much wrong here (see my answer, I really hate this question) with the code in the question, but your answer doesn't make any sense, of course you can use traits of an abstract class! Anyway, I'm leaving this question now because the code is so convoluted.

Comment: You've done a much better job simplifying it down to : Be does not extend Ae, and the compiler is expecting an Ae .. what its getting has not implemented message as part of Ae. No duck typing in C++ :)